# Which statistics test to be used in the following test?

Tags: statistics

To test if 65% of the student population is male? (significance 0.05)

[Sample data attached in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUwbi.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve the problem

- Z test for proportions
- chi square test (non parametric test)

Comment: Thank you for answer